# Perform percentile calculations within a VBA individually on rows with a changing range

Tags: excel, vba, percentile

Firstly I'm having issues setting up the percentile application not sure what to put as array and as myVar. I've had a look at a few codes and not sure what and why they put certain values there.

Secondly I want two different percentile calculations to run on rows 16-79 which each are unique to each other. The columns can't be set as the range changes from sheet to sheet. 
I have code below which finds the last column with data and creates 2 columns: "20th Percentile" and "80th Percentile" after it. So I'm thinking this can be used to help in setting up the range. 
This needs to be ran on multiple sheets.

```
Sub create_columns_test2()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer

    Dim array(???) As Variant?
    'What do I set my array as? why variant?
    Dim myVar as Double?
    'What does double mean

    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        With WS

            If .Cells.Find("20th Percentile") Is Nothing And _
               .Cells.Find("80th Percentile") Is Nothing Then

                x = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
                .Cells(16, x + 2).Value = "20th Percentile"
                myVar = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Array(16, x - 1), 0.2)
                .Cells(16, x + 3).Value = "80th Percentile"
                myVar = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Array(16, x - 2), 0.8)
                'I want the percentile to run from rows 16 to 79 individually
                    'from column C to the column before the matching column I've just created

            End If

        End With

    Next WS

  For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    WS.Range("N:Q").EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) is the description of data types. Could you add some screenshots of your data, 'cos I'm not sure I understand correct what `.Cells.Find("20th Percentile")` does. And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type) is explanation on Variant.

Comment: That part of the code just searches the sheet for "20th Percentile" and if it does find it then the code won't run on that sheet

Comment: because my array will change from sheet to sheet, do I make it a dynamic array?

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution. Read comments in code, if something isn't clear - ask in comments.
First note - I didn't quite understand how would you like to use percentile in the manner:

> I want the percentile to run from rows 16 to 79 individually

but I think you will be able to fix function's arguments.

```
Sub create_columns_test2()

    Dim WS As Worksheet

    ' give variables proper names - I've used colNo instead of x for column number (see Note 1 in post)
    Dim colNo As Long
    Dim rowNo As Long

    ' Don't need this at all
'    Dim array(???) As Variant?
'    'What do I set my array as? why variant?
'    Dim myVar as Double?
'    'What does double mean


    ' be careful with using ActiveWorkbook / Sheet (see Note 2 in post)
    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        With WS

            If .Cells.Find("20th Percentile") Is Nothing And _
               .Cells.Find("80th Percentile") Is Nothing Then


                ' using .UsedRange.Columns.Count is very tricky and may
                ' return incorrect data
                colNo = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                ' Set column headers - Ok
                .Cells(16, colNo + 2).Value = "20th Percentile"
                .Cells(16, colNo + 3).Value = "80th Percentile"

                'I want the percentile to run from rows 16 to 79 individually
                    For rowNo = 17 To 79
                         'from column C to the column before the matching column I've just created

                         ' this part takes data from column C:
                         .Cells(rowNo, colNo + 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Range(.Cells(rowNo, 3), .Cells(rowNo, colNo)), 0.2)
                         .Cells(rowNo, colNo + 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Range(.Cells(rowNo, 3), .Cells(rowNo, colNo)), 0.8)
                    Next
            End If

        End With

    ' Don't need separate loop - can do it after each iteration
    WS.Range("N:Q").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next WS


End Sub
```

**Note 1**
Refer to [Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/naming-conventions). There are also some other naming conventions in the web, which are like "for vba" and suggest to use a prefix based on type name, but personally I am against of that.  But in general, those also mean one simple thing - when you get back to your code in a month - you won't remember at once what that variable `x` or `y` means, but you will definitely know what `colNo` or `rowNo` are used for.

**Note 2**
Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999) and decide whether you really want to use `ActiveWorkbook` here, because the workbook where the code is placed not always an active one.

Comment: Get a "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Percentile property of the WorksheetFunction class" on line `.Cells(rowNo, colNo + 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(.Cells(rowNo, 3), 0.2)`